# Perform an Xpath descendant search in jsoup

Tags: xpath, jsoup

Here is my Xpath query i'm trying to convert to jsoup..

```
//div[@id='ad-display']/descendant-or-self::img[contains(@class, 'absmiddle')]/@src
```

I can't find any documentation that talks about descendants in jsoup.  I know it talks about child elements, but apparently I'm not good enough to find the correlation between the two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSoup uses CSS selectors, selecting descendant in CSS is easy, just put your descendant element after ancestor separated by space.

Select by id is done with '#'. And select by class with '.'

Putting all together:

```
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse("<div id='ad-display'><div><div>" +
            "<img class='2'></img>" +
            "<img class='absmiddle' src='src1'></img>" +
            "<img class='dummy'></img>" +
            "<img class='absmiddle' src='src2'></img>" +
            "</div></div></div>");
    Elements select = doc.select("div#ad-display img.absmiddle");
    for (Element elem : select)
        System.out.println(elem.attr("src"));
```

I added a mini-html as an example. Note imgs are inside a div inside a div inside the ancestor div (with id 'ad-display')

The output would be:

```
src1
src2
```

As expected.

I hope it will help.